# Assert File not validating

Tags: php, file, symfony, mime-types, assert

I have followed the instructions on the documentation for how to handle file upload using Doctrine.

Image upload works fine but when I upload some other file type, it just lets the file upload even if I have properly set the annotation on the $file property like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSizeMessage = "L'image ne doit pas dépasser 5Mb.",
 *     maxSize = "5000k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Les images doivent être au format JPG, GIF ou PNG."
 * )
 */
public $file;
```

Comment: Yes but it's not triggering any errors.

Comment: Then you've got a few options 1.) Everything is okay 2.) You don't run the assertion 3.) Those are run but you don't process the outcome. From the code you've shown so far and from the description you've given so far everything is possible. So this needs further troubleshooting on your end first.

Comment: How do you run/process an assertion ?

Comment: That depends, it's outlined in the manual. Normally through entity validation. Also it's probably an issue that you've got a public property here. Who suggested you to make it public? That's normally not in the manual (of which you've written you followed it).

Comment: Also check if the MimeTypeGuesser actually works. Looks like you've found out that it doesn't [according to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14096450/367456). Maybe that's your issue?

Comment: @hakre - I'm a little confused about annoations in Symfony. If like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#constraint-configuration) under the *Annotations* tab, is that part of the DI or compile time directives that then, by itself , fires a `ConstraintViolation`, or are annotations what I think they, just for the docs? And I suppose they might help in unit testing...?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: That is just different ways of doing the same, the annotations is just one out of the four. It's configuration, so for running the program, not documenting it (only).

Comment: @hakre - Really. So annotations, like the `@Assert\File` above or `@Assert\NotBlank()`, just by being in an annotation can affect the processing within the method or class it's describing? I was thinking you had to do YAML and PHP for it to work. It's a bit overwhelming, like where do you start. Lots of great stuff though.

Comment: @hakre The $file property is public according to the cookbook here http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html
I should probably write my own type guesser for this. I'll answer this post once I make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yes, you can choose any of those methods: Either in XML or YAML configuration files, with the Annotations in the PHP docblocks comments or by assigning the functionality programmatically with PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out that the problem was coming from the Product entity. I was adding multiple images to a Product form and I forgot to put the Valid assert to the $images property on the Product entity like so :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PS\StockBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $images;
```

I wrote an article on my blog about this here https://web.archive.org/web/20141004165731/http://www.ennazk.com:80/validate-subforms-in-symfony2/#.Wdt9mBNSwnU

Thanks.

Comment: the article is not available more? how did you fix it ?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20141004165731/http://www.ennazk.com:80/validate-subforms-in-symfony2/#.Wdt9mBNSwnU

Answer (score 0):

Is `{"image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"},` valid json? because that does not look like a valid json for me (objects in json consist of key=>value pairs.). If json decode fails, then it is possible the entire assertion does not get applied. I don;t know that much about doctrine though, so i might be wrong.

Comment: Look at the [Annotations tab under Basic Usage](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/File.html#basic-usage) on the File constraints page. It's `{'string', 'string'}`.